# How to load a map object from yml with Enviroment.getProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

the yml looks like this

```
class:
  student:
    name:bob
    number:12213550
    gender:male
```

I want load the 'student' as a map via Enviroment.getProperties("student",Map.class), but only get a null.

I can load it with @ConfigurationProperties, which is weird since I was told they are actually similar.

what's the difference between them? and how can I get this map with Enviroment Object?

Comment: Which `Environment` class are you talking about specifically?

Comment: org.springframework.core.env.Environment